# New app in FireBase

Tags: ios, firebase

I have recently started to use FireBase to see how it works, as a possible replacement (at least in some cases) for Parse.com.

Here I have a few questions related to that.

1) I noticed from start that an app was automatically built for me. Am I allowed to change its name?
2) I now would like to create a second app. Is that possible or do I need to upgrade my account? Or how do I do? I can see no place in the dashboard for that purpose.

Thanks in advance for any useful indication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your questions:

1. You can change the name but not the url of you app. In your dashboard click on the cogwheel next to the name of your app, in the menu that pops up there is an option to change the name.
2. You can create a second app by simply filling in a name in the gray field on the left and click "CREATE NEW APP"

[image]